# Как написать событие, которое будет отслеживать только первую загрузку страницы?

Tags: javascript

Есть задача: при первой загрузке сайта открывается скрытая панель меню и с поочередным подмигиванием пунктов меню, демонстрируется их наличие, после меню закрывается.
Часть задачи уже выполнил, остался главный момент - это запуск этой демонстрации только при первой загрузке сайт, при всех последующих, пользователь будет открывать панель с помощью кнопки.
Прошу помочь советами или может у кого есть готовое решение в данной задачи?

Comment: 1) Куки.  2) localStorage

Answer (score 1):

При загрузке проверять наличие определенного значения в [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)/[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) и т.д.

Если значения нет: загрузка первая - нужно установить это значение и показать демонстрацию.

Если значение есть: загрузка не первая - ничего не нужно показывать.